# How to compute the percentage of failed tasks in Google AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I am using [push task queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) from GAE (python). There are times when after X minutes, Y% of the tasks have failed.
For this situation, I want to purge the task queue (there is no need to execute them, eventually many will fail).

I can configure for a task to stop executing if it retries more than 2 times, but if I have 100 tasks that failed (300 runs = 100 + 200 retries) how can I stop the remaining tasks to execute?

*queue.yaml:*

```
queue:
- name: my-queue
  mode: push
  rate: 1/s
  bucket_size: 10
  max_concurrent_requests: 10
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store some values in memcache, like `number of tasks in queue` and `timestamps of tasks that failed`.

Each task would need to perform these tasks:

- on start, calculate the rolling percentage (within last X minutes) and exit if the percentage is too high, or increment the `number of tasks` counter and proceed.
- on failure,
  decrement the `number of tasks` counter and add a timestamp to the
  `failed tasks` list.
- on success, decrement the `number of tasks`
  counter.

To calculate the rolling percentage, take the entire list of `failed tasks` and filter out those timestamps that are too old (over X minutes ago).  Put the new list back into memcache.  Then, take the `number of tasks` counter and calculate `100.0 * (number of failed tasks) / (number of tasks)` to get your percentage.  If it exceeds the Y% threshold, exit your task immediately.